# How to get anchor text/href on click using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, anchor

Consider I have an anchor which looks like this

```
 <div class="res">
     <a href="~/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.docx">
         ~/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.docx
     </a>
 </div>
```

**NOTE:** There won't be any id or class for the anchor...

I want to get either href/text in the jQuery `onclick` of that anchor.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

**Note:** Apply the class `info_link` to any link you want to get the info from.

```
<a class="info_link" href="~/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.docx">
    ~/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.docx
</a>
```

**For href:**

```
$(function(){
  $('.info_link').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    // or alert($(this).hash();
  });
});
```

**For Text:**

```
$(function(){
  $('.info_link').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

.

## Update Based On Question Edit

You can get them like this now:

**For href:**

```
$(function(){
  $('div.res a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    // or alert($(this).hash();
  });
});
```

**For Text:**

```
$(function(){
  $('div.res a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: This will break if another element has the class name link. Better to specify tag selector also.

Comment: @rahul: It is funny, it won't, the `link` class is supposed to be for the specific links he wants to get info from.

Comment: But what if the following markup is there, `<div class='link' />`

Comment: @rahul: it is becoming funny again, he could give his links any unique name.

Comment: you could use the this.hash instead of $(this).attr('href')

Answer (score 7):

**Edited to reflect update to question**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".res a").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Comment: that will target all links even the ones he might not be interested in

Answer (score 5):

### Without jQuery:

You don't *need* jQuery when it is so simple to do this using pure JavaScript. Here are two options:

- **Method 1 - Retrieve the exact value of the `href` attribute:**

  Select the element and then use the [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) method.

  This method does *not* return the full URL, instead it retrieves the exact value of the `href` attribute.

  ```js
  var anchor = document.querySelector('a'),
      url = anchor.getAttribute('href');

  alert(url);
  ```

  ```html
  <a href="/relative/path.html"></a>
  ```

---

- **Method 2 - Retrieve the full URL path:**

  Select the element and then simply access the [`href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.href).

  This method returns the full URL path.

  In this case: `http://stacksnippets.net/relative/path.html`.

  ```js
  var anchor = document.querySelector('a'),
      url = anchor.href;

  alert(url);
  ```

  ```html
  <a href="/relative/path.html"></a>
  ```

---

As your title implies, you want to get the `href` value on click. Simply select an element, add a click event listener and then return the `href` value using either of the aforementioned methods.

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector('a'),
    button = document.getElementById('getURL'),
    url = anchor.href;

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  alert(url);
});
```

```html
<button id="getURL">Click me!</button>
<a href="/relative/path.html"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Updated code***

```
$('a','div.res').click(function(){
  var currentAnchor = $(this);
  alert(currentAnchor.text());
  alert(currentAnchor.attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: that will target all links even the ones he might not be interested in.

Comment: But this is according to his markup in which he hasn't specified a class name.

Comment: You should guide him where improvement is possible :)

Comment: possible reason for the down vote could be that questioner is not looking for what you have done with `$('a','div.res')`

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative

Using the example from Sarfraz above.

```
<div class="res">
    <a class="info_link" href="~/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.docx">
        ~/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.docx
    </a>
</div>
```

#### For href:

```
$(function(){
  $('.res').on('click', '.info_link', function(){
    alert($(this)[0].href);
  });
});
```