# jquery sender BY CLASS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<img href="a" class="myImg"></img>
<img href="b" class="myImg"></img>
<img href="c" class="myImg"></img>
```

How can I determine the href value of the image being clicked maybe by tracking click events on elements using css class myImg. You can also modify the html if it simplifies the jquery.Thanks

Comment: I recommend to have a look at a [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get anchor text/href on click using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652372/how-to-get-anchor-text-href-on-click-using-jquery)

Comment: Btw. `href` is not a valid attribute for images. Do you mean `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img.myImg').click(function(){
    alert(this.href); //might not work
    alert(this.getAttribute('href')); //definitely should work
});
```

Comment: I think this answer is not correct as IMG tag doesn't have a HREF attribute, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myImg').click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Haha SO wouldn't post mine because it was the **exact** same answer as yours (but 5 seconds later!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.myImg').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myImg").click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"img" tag doesn't have a "href" attribute. You have to put those images between link tags ("a");

```
<a href="a"><img src=".." class="myImg"></a>
<a href="b"><img src=".." class="myImg"></a>
<a href="c"><img src=".." class="myImg"></a>
```

Then if you want to get the href, listen for the click event on the link;

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    console.log('selected href:', $(this).attr('href'));
    // if you want you can stop executing the href
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/demods/U7D2g/