# how to display image and text in div from file

Tags: php, html, href

In my website i have lots of file and i `href` file to div using this method

```
<a href="file.php">
    <div class="file preview">
          Show file preview with images
    </div>
</a>
```

### External file div

```
<div id="display">
display this content in index file
</div>
```

As above code i linked file to div, now my problem is i need to add `img` to div and `text` to div description

Is there any way to display one image from file and some text from file linked to div almost like preview

How can i do that

Can some one help me

Comment: What type of file is it? Word document, PDF, html?

Comment: @GRC its html i don't want to `<iframe>` is there any other method

Comment: Yes, there is using javascript.

Comment: @GRC that div should display first image `<img src="" alt="pro pic">` and some text from `<h1>` tag

Comment: how?? can you show me some example

Comment: I have no idea if this will be useful to you: Are you aware of 'oocss' and the _media object_? Your favorite internet search engine will be helpful.... Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @RyanVincent i just tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652372/how-to-get-anchor-text-href-on-click-using-jquery and it doesn't works for me

Comment: @GRC your answer doesn't works can you please help

Answer (score 2):

finally found solution

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'topic/ginger.php',
            success: function (data) {
                data = $(data).find('div#display');
                $('.res h2').html(data);
                            }
        });
```

Comment: Good job for finding answer your self :)