# Is there a way to simulate a link/button click in mink?

Tags: phantomjs, functional-testing, mink

I'm using a headless browser ([phantomjs](https://github.com/jcalderonzumba/MinkPhantomJSDriver)) in conjunction with **Mink** to do some functional testing on my Website. 
Now in this setting, files can not be downloaded regularly e.g: by clicking a link. So I have to extract the url from the **link** or the **button**, and download the file manually.

As I just stated sometimes there is no link () for the download, but a **button in a Form** (e.g: Inputting data for a report in the form, and receiving the report file on submission).

So what I need to do is ***simulate*** clicking the link or button and extract the Data for the Request that *would have been* sent, and use that data to download the file manually.

Is there a way to do this?
*Note*: I'm using `guzzle` to actually download the file.

Comment: You should have a find method from Mink that you can use to find the element, this method will return an object and from there you can use click or you can get the href attribute that should give you the url you need. For click you should use find by css and click.

Comment: I know, that's why noted that it's not necessarily a link. The request sent for the file could even be a `POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm... I don't know if you solved this and only as an alternative to typical mink methods. As Phantomjs is a javascript based browser engine, did you tried with javascript?

You could try something like this:

```
public function getElementHref($element)
{
    /* @var FeatureContext $this */
    $function = "(function(){
        //Javascript method to get the href.
    })()";
    try {
        return $this->featureContext->getSession()->evaluateScript($function);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception('Element not found');
    }
}
```

You can find a method to do this in javascript here: [How to get anchor text/href on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652372/how-to-get-anchor-text-href-on-click-using-jquery)

Then use the URL returned with file_get_contents (depending on the file type) and that's it.