# How to pass ID to controller and use it to display data on modal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have passed the `UserID` to the table as shown in the code:

[image]

**View**

```
@foreach (var user in Model.RIROUsers)
{ 
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">@(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName)</td>
    <td><a href="a href="~/Views/RIRO/id=@user.UserID" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="@user.UserID">View Details</button></a>
</tr>
}
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                        <label for="">* Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="">

                        <label for="">* Birthday</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="">

                        <label for="">* Contact</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new RIROViewModel();
    vm.RIROUsers = new List<ResourceViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in db_RIRO.sp_GetAllRIRORoster())
    {
        vm.RIROUsers.Add(new ResourceViewModel()
        {
            EID = user.EID,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            EmployeeType = user.EmployeeType,
            ProjectName = user.ProjectName,
            JobTitle = user.JobTitle,
            Level = user.CareerLevel,
            ACNRollOn = user.HireDate,
            ManagerName = user.Manager,
            LeadName = user.Supervisor,
            UserID = user.UserID
        });
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now when I click `View Details` I want the details of the user to display on the modal. What would be the best approach on this? I'm thinking of creating another stored procedure to retrieve the User's details and display it on the modal. But how do I do this?

EDIT 1: Changed button to `a href=~/Views/RIRO/id=@user.UserID`

Comment: You do not directly access a view. You access it via an action method. So point the href to the action method `<A href='@Url.Action("Details","User", new { id=user.UserID})'>view details</a>`

Comment: Wouldn't that redirect me to another view? My modal is in the same view.

Comment: With javascript, you have to hijack the click event and show modal instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Shyju said, use `click` DOM event to the anchor link to show modal popup. Here are the steps:

1) Put `Url.Action` with proper controller and action name into `href` attribute of anchor link, then assign a class name to help identify each link.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "User", new { id = user.UserID })" 
   class="btn btn-xs btn-primary details" data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="@user.UserID">View Details</a>
```

2) Handle `click` DOM event using JS which rather than opening a new window/tab in browser, it should open modal popup instead (by using `jQuery.ajax()`, `jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.load()`):

```
$('.details').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // this is required

    // get target action
    var action = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(action, function (data) {
        $(this).find(".modal-body").html(data);
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    });
});

// alternative way
$('.details').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // this is required

    // get target action
    var action = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.modal-body').load(action, function () {
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

3) Ensure that target action method returns partial view which will loaded to the modal popup.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var vm = new RIROViewModel();

    // do something to retrieve data from DB

    return PartialView("_Details", vm);
}
```

References:

[Implementing Bootstrap Modal Popup In MVC Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/092589/implementing-modal-pop-up-in-mvc-application/)

[How to get anchor text/href on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652372/how-to-get-anchor-text-href-on-click-using-jquery)